# Custom Component visible in Sandbox but not in Production

Tags: controller, visualforce-component, security

I created a few custom components to use in two different email templates (they all use the same controller class) and everything is working as it should at the Sandbox.

But when I deployed it in Production, the custom components stopped being displayed.

I already checked the data and it's ok.
The controller class security is set correctly.
There's only one custom field, and it's visibility is also set correctly.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you by chance verified that there is data in the custom field in the production instance?

Comment: Hi TC Sutton, thanks for your your time.

Yes, there's data in the custom field in both Production and Sandbox instances. And there's data in the other fields used in all new Custom Components as well.

Comment: Are there any specific SOQL queries that may be hardcoded to a specific ID? Would need to see more of the components to see what could be causing the error. Any errors in the debug log?

Comment: I just found the issue. I copied the SOQL queries and tried to execute it on Force.com Explorer. The tool showed me a Custom Field was not available. Another developer created this custom field and forgot to tell the team.

When I set the custom field security level, the custom component started to be displayed correctly. 

Thanks for all your help.